# How can I examine the `StateEntries` property?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, exception, watch

I got the error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException : Invalid data encountered. A required relationship is missing. Examine StateEntries to determine the source of the constraint violation.

So, I changed the code which throws the exception. Now I am catching the exception with an aim to read the `StateEntries`. But I am not able to find the `StateEntries` inside the exception with the help of the Watch window in Visual Studio 2019.

```
try
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var stop = 0; //I put a breakpoint here and examine the **e**
}
```

[image]

Could you, please, point me a property in the exception which elaborates the `StateEntries`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try drilling into the InnerException's until you get to the innermost one.